# Using prepositions "through" and "via".

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Are the prepositions "through" and "via" interchangeable (meaning "by means of", "by using")? 
[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/through) says that the word "through" has also the meaning "by means of".

Is it okay to use it in the such context?

> If the connection quality is bad during the call, try calling
>   **through/via** backup provider.

Comment: Both of those sound equally poor to me. I would rephrase the sentence to something like: *try* ***using a*** *backup provider*. Or, *try* ***placing your call with a*** *backup provider*. However, in this particular sentence, I would say that both *through* and *via* can be used to the same effect.

Comment: When there are common collocations available, as in **try placing the call with** as Jason says in his comment, but you do not use them, your writing can sound very wooden, grammatical but unidiomatic. You could greatly simplify that statement: *If the connection is poor, try placing the call with another provider.*  When would the connection quality not be **during the call**? Does that phrase really serve any purpose?